# Why is the printable item disappear from Printing queue after closing the connection and nothing happens?

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I'm using SMB shared printers to print labels ( Zebra printer ) written in ZPL from IIS backend.
The printable item is in the Queue while i'm closing the connection but the printer do not print the data.
I've checked the System32\Spool\Printers and the SDL has data but SPL is empty. 
There is no errors, the JobStream.Close(); the connection and the item is disappearing.
I've googled a lot and checked the similar questions but I did not find the answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is quite an old post, but thought I would add this as I have been having similar problems printing to Zebra printers from C#.

It turned out that a way that I could work around this was to set the "Keep printed documents"  checkbox in the advanced tab of the printer settings.

Not only was the printer then retaining the document, but it was also actually printing out the document, whereas previously the document was disappearing from the queue without printing.